# How to get request from a Google Calendar API on a Hugo site in a Netlify lambda function

Tags: javascript, lambda, google-calendar-api, hugo, netlify

I am trying to make a get request to the `Google Calendar API` inside a `Netlify lambda function` for a Hugo Site but I am not able to do so without Node which I can't use.

I tried using fetch, `XMLHttpRequest` and to do so I tried using zip-it-and-ship -it but it doesn't work and I am not able to get any node module to work since the site is not made with `Node.js` but with Hugo.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var fetch = require("node-fetch");
    var makeQuerystring = params =>
        Object.keys(params)
        .map(key => {
            return encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
        })
        .join("&");

    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarid/events";
    var querystring = makeQuerystring({
        q: "Makerspace"
    });
    var today = new Date();

    var yearRn = today.getFullYear();
    var monthRn = today.getMonth()+1;
    var dayRn = today.getDate();
    var hoursRn = today.getHours();
    var minutesRn = today.getMinutes();
    var datetime = new Date(yearRn, monthRn, dayRn, hoursRn, 00,00);
    var indexarray = [];
    fetch(url + "?" + querystring, {
        method: "get",
        headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + {{APIKEY}}
        }
    })

    callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: resObj,
      });
  };
```

I am expecting to get an object with a bunch of events in it with which I can then work with to then bring it onto the website via the callback. But I am actually not getting a response from the api since the request never gets made: "Error: Cannot find module 'node-fetch'". The Callback works as I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle up the modules with your functions, if those dependencies are not included in node already. In this case, you will have to bundle `node-fetch` with your function.

There will need to be an existing module for your bundle. There is 2 ways you can do this within a project:

- Bring the node_modules dependencies with you from the function directory **or**
- Pre-build your modules with a bundler (like webpack) into your script and target a node build

These might seem like a lot of work, but in most cases it is simpler than it seems.

[@philhawksworth](https://github.com/philhawksworth) shows an example in a starter repository of a function that uses the first method above by `npm install` using a local package.json config for `node-fetch` [here](https://github.com/philhawksworth/eleventyone/tree/master/src/functions/fetch-joke). Then the results are stored into the repository, so Netlify can pick them up when creating the functions. There is no pre-build needed.

The second option would use the same method as [this repository](https://github.com/netlify/functions) where your functions exist in a source location and are bundled to a distribution location using the `netlify-lambda` cli.

***Note:*** Think of each function directory as a self contained script that will be running in its own node instance without any node modules install. The function needs all dependencies installed into its directory prior to being deployed. Both of the cases above meet this requirement.

Comment: I have done exactly as it is done in the 1st variant but it is still not working and displaying the same error. I don't know how to do the second variant so I am stuck again, I was wondering if there is something that I could be doing wrong even though it is the same as the repository that is linked?